# If for each rational $q$ the set $f^ {−1} ((q,\infty])$ is measurable then $f$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I want to prove that If for each rational $q$ the set $f^ {−1} ((q,\infty])$ is measurable then $f$ is measurable.

My attempt is the following:

if $f^{−1}
((q, \infty])$ is measurable for all $q$, then for each real $\lambda$
$f^{−1}((λ,\infty)) = \cup _{q>λ}f
^−1
((q, \infty])$
is measurable as a countable union of measurable set.

Comment: Why do you say $\lambda$ is rational?

Comment: @JohnHughes I have fixed it. That should be real. Thanks

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path. Given $r\in\mathbb R$, $\exists (q_n)\subset\mathbb Q:q_n\downarrow r$. Hence,
$$f^{-1}\left(\left]r,\infty\right]\right) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left]q_n,\infty\right]\right) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} f^{-1}\left(\left]q_n,\infty\right]\right)\in\mathcal F.$$

Simulatenously, you may prove that, given $p\in\mathbb Q$ then $f^{-1}\left(\left[-\infty,p\right]\right)$ is also measurable. Finally, given $s\in\mathbb R$, $\exists(p_n)\subset\mathbb Q:p_n\uparrow s$ and 
$$f^{-1}\left(\left[-\infty,s\right[\right) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[-\infty,p_n\right]\right) = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} f^{-1}\left(\left[-\infty,p_n\right]\right)\in\mathcal F.$$